# In PowerShell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?

Tags: powershell, join, scripting

I'm fairly new to PowerShell, and am wondering if someone knows of any better way to accomplish the following example problem.

I have an array of mappings from IP address to host-name. This represents a list of active DHCP leases:

```
PS H:\> $leases

IP                    Name
--                    ----
192.168.1.1           Apple
192.168.1.2           Pear
192.168.1.3           Banana
192.168.1.99          FishyPC
```

I have another array of mappings from MAC address to IP address.  This represents a list of IP reservations:

```
PS H:\> $reservations

IP                    MAC
--                    ---
192.168.1.1           001D606839C2
192.168.1.2           00E018782BE1
192.168.1.3           0022192AF09C
192.168.1.4           0013D4352A0D
```

For convenience, I was able to produce a third array of mappings from MAC address to IP address and host name using the following code. The idea is that `$reservations` should get a third field, "Name", which is populated whenever there's a matching "IP" field:

```
$reservations = $reservations | foreach {
    $res = $_
    $match = $leases | where {$_.IP -eq $res.IP} | select -unique
    if ($match -ne $NULL) {
        "" | select @{n="IP";e={$res.IP}}, @{n="MAC";e={$res.MAC}}, @{n="Name";e={$match.Name}}
    }
}
```

The desired output is something like this:

```
PS H:\> $ideal

IP                    MAC                 Name
--                    ---                 ----
192.168.1.1           001D606839C2        Apple
192.168.1.2           00E018782BE1        Pear
192.168.1.3           0022192AF09C        Banana
192.168.1.4           0013D4352A0D
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: @Michael How were you able to get a table for IP Address to Host Name for all active leases? I have been using the DHCP module but can not figure it out. I am also trying to combine some tables.

Comment: @Ruisu I was using `netsh`'s dhcp command to get a listing, and then parsing the output with regular expressions. There is also the [DHCP Server Management API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363376(v=VS.85).aspx), but it is only available to native code. I'm not aware of any powershell module or .net library for doing this kind of thing. I ended up writing P/Invoke wrappers to the DHCP Server Management API.

Answer (score 39):

After 1.5 years, the cmdlet I had pasted in the original answer has undergone so many updates that it has become completely outdated. Therefore I have replaced the [code and the ReadMe](https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object) with a link to the latest version.

### [Join-Object](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule)

Combines two object lists based on a related property between them.

**Description**
Combines properties from one or more objects. It creates a set that can be saved as a new object or used as it is. An object join is a means for combining properties from one (self-join) or more object lists by using values common to each.

**Main features**

- An intuitive idiomatic PowerShell syntax
- SQL like joining features
- Smart property merging
- Predefined join commands for updating, merging and specific join types
- Well defined pipeline for the (left) input objects and output objects (preserves memory when correctly used)
- Performs about twice as fast as Compare-Object on large object lists
- Supports (custom) objects, data tables and dictionaries (e.g. hash tables) for input
- Smart properties and calculated property expressions
- Custom relation expressions
- Easy installation (dot-sourcing)
- Supports PowerShell for Windows (5.1) and PowerShell Core

The Join-Object cmdlet reveals the following proxy commands with their own (`-JoinType` and `-Property`) defaults:

- `InnerJoin-Object` (Alias `InnerJoin` or `Join`), combines the related objects
- `LeftJoin-Object` (Alias `LeftJoin`), combines the related objects and adds the rest of the left objects
- `RightJoin-Object` (Alias `RightJoin`), combines the related objects and adds the rest of the right objects
- `FullJoin-Object` (Alias `FullJoin`), combines the related objects and adds the rest of the left and right objects
- `CrossJoin-Object` (Alias `CrossJoin`), combines each left object with each right object
- `Update-Object` (Alias `Update`), updates the left object with the related right object
- `Merge-Object` (Alias `Merge`), updates the left object with the related right object and adds the rest of the new (unrelated) right objects

### [ReadMe](https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object)

The full ReadMe (and source code) is available from GitHub: https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object

### Installation

There are two versions of this `Join-Object` cmdlet (both versions supply the same functionality):

- [**Join Module**](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule)

```
Install-Module -Name JoinModule
```

- [**Join Script**](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)

```
Install-Script -Name Join
```

(or rename the `Join.psm1` module to a `Join.ps1` script file)
and invoked the script by [**dot sourcing**](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-6#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing):

```
. .\Join.ps1
```

### Answer

To answer the actual example in the question:

```
$reservations |LeftJoin $leases -On IP

IP          MAC          Name
--          ---          ----
192.168.1.1 001D606839C2 Apple
192.168.1.2 00E018782BE1 Pear
192.168.1.3 0022192AF09C Banana
192.168.1.4 0013D4352A0D
```

### Performance

A little word on performance measuring:
The PowerShell pipeline is designed to *stream* objects (which saves memory), meaning that both¹ lists of **input objects usually aren't** (shouldn't be) **resident in memory**. Normally they are retrieved from somewhere else (i.e. a remote server or a disk). Also, **the output** usually **matters** where [**`linq`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) solutions are fast but might easily put you on the wrong foot in drawing conclusions because `linq` literally *defers* the execution ([lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)), see also: [fastest way to get a uniquely index item from the property of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59437162/1701026).
In other words, if it comes to (measuring) performance in PowerShell, it is important to look to the **complete end-to-end solution**, which is more likely to look something like:

```
 import-csv .\reservations.csv |LeftJoin (import-csv .\leases.csv) -On IP |Export-Csv .\results.csv
```

<sub>(1) Note: unfortunately, there is no easy way to build ***two*** parallel input streams (see: [`#15206` Deferred input pipelines](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15206))</sub>

### (more) Examples

More examples can be found in the related Stack Overflow questions at:

- [Combining Multiple CSV Files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54855458/1701026)
- [CMD or Powershell command to combine (merge) corresponding lines from two files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54607741/1701026)
- [Can I use SQL commands (such as join) on objects in powershell, without any SQL server/database involved?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55431393/1701026)
- [Powershell match properties and then selectively combine objects to create a third](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54855647/1701026)
- [Compare Two CSVs, match the columns on 2 or more Columns, export specific columns from both csvs with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52235645/1701026)
- [Merge two CSV files while adding new and overwriting existing entries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54949056/1701026)
- [Merging two CSVs and then re-ordering columns on output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54981257/1701026)
- [Efficiently merge large object datasets having multiple matching keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55543321/1701026)
- [How to compare two CSV files and output the rows that are in either of the file but not in both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72012355/1701026)
- [How to join two CSV files in Powershell with SQL LIKE syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73712540/1701026)

**side-by-side join examples**

- [Combine two CSVs - Add CSV as another Column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55431240/1701026)
- [Is there a PowerShell equivalent of `paste` (i.e., horizontal file concatenation)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68070763/1701026)
- [How can merge 3 cycle and export in one table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74812558/1701026)
- [Merging two arrays object into one array object in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75331465/1701026)
- [s there a way to transform horizontally formatted CSV output to vertical when converting XML to CSV in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76330651/1701026)
- [How to import this Json data as a flat object rather than a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77022611/1701026)

And in the [Join-Object test script](https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object/blob/master/Tests/Join-Object.Tests.ps1).

<sub>Please give a  if you support the proposal to [Add a Join-Object cmdlet to the standard PowerShell equipment (`#14994`)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14994)</sub>

Comment: Great function, but **careful** if using it from inside a Powershell module. Because of the way that scoping works, the `$Left` and `$Right` variables will not be available in the `-Merge` script block (modules' variables are private to the module, hence the script block cannot see them). This is not an issue if dot sourcing or including the function directly in the script that's calling it.

Comment: @Omni, I did some testing with putting the cmdlet in a module but couldn't confirm your issue. Nevertheless, during revising the cmdlet I found a rather big bug which is described at [Unexpected results when reusing custom objects in the pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192685/unexpected-results-when-reusing-a-custom-object-for-the-pipeline). I have created a branched version, which pasted in this answer. I suspect that this is actually the issue you ran into (I will appreciate it if you could confirm whether or not this is the case).

Answer (score 5):

This can also be done using my module [Join-Object](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join-Object/)

```
Install-Module 'Join-Object'

Join-Object -Left $leases -Right $reservations -LeftJoinProperty 'IP' -RightJoinProperty 'IP'
```

Regarding performance, I tested against a sample data of 100k lines:

1. Hashtable example posted by [@js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010) run in 8 seconds.
2. `Join-Object` by me run in 14 seconds.
3. `LeftJoin` by [@iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) run in 1 minute and 50 seconds

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way I've found to Merge two Powershell Objects is using ConvertTo-Json and ConvertFrom-Json

**One liner based on the OPs Senario:**

```
$leases | foreach {(ConvertTo-Json $_) -replace ("}$", (ConvertTo-Json ($reservations | where IP -eq $_.IP | select * -ExcludeProperty IP)) -Replace "^{", ",")} 
| ConvertFrom-Json
```

Results in:

```
IP          Name  Mac
--          ----  ---
192.168.1.1 Apple 001D606839C2
192.168.1.2 Pear  00E018782BE1
```

For another example lets make a couple objects:

```
$object1 = [PSCustomObject]@{"A" = "1"; "B" = "2"}
$object2 = [PSCustomObject]@{"C" = "3"; "D" = "4"}
```

**Merge them together using Json by replacing the opening and closing brackets:**

```
(ConvertTo-Json $object1) -replace ("}$", $((ConvertTo-Json $object2) -Replace "^{", ",")) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Output:

```
A B C D
- - - -
1 2 3 4
```

**Another example using a group of objects:**

```
$mergedObjects = [PSCustomObject]@{"Object1" = $Object1; "Object2" = $Object2}
```

```
Object1     Object2
-------     -------
@{A=1; B=2} @{C=3; D=4}
```

Can just do the same again within a foreach:

```
$mergedObjects | foreach {(ConvertTo-Json $_.Object1) -replace ("}$", $((ConvertTo-Json $_.Object2) -Replace "^{", ",")) | ConvertFrom-Json}
```

Output:

```
A B C D
- - - -
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use script block like this

```
$leases | select IP, NAME, @{N='MAC';E={$tmp=$_.IP;($reservations| ? IP -eq $tmp).MAC}}
```

Comment: +1 for arguably the most "powershell-y" way to do it without a third-party module.  Although I do find the original foreach option more readable IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example using a hashtable.  With big arrays, this turns out to be faster.

```
$leases =
'IP,Name
192.168.1.1,Apple
192.168.1.2,Pear
192.168.1.3,Banana
192.168.1.99,FishyPC' | convertfrom-csv

$reservations =
'IP,MAC
192.168.1.1,001D606839C2
192.168.1.2,00E018782BE1
192.168.1.3,0022192AF09C
192.168.1.4,0013D4352A0D' | convertfrom-csv

$hashRes=@{}
foreach ($resRecord in $reservations) {
  $hashRes[$resRecord.IP] = $resRecord
}

$leases | foreach {
  $other = $hashRes[$_.IP]

  [pscustomobject]@{IP=$_.IP
                   MAC=$other.MAC
                  Name=$_.name}
}
```

```
IP           MAC          Name
--           ---          ----
192.168.1.1  001D606839C2 Apple
192.168.1.2  00E018782BE1 Pear
192.168.1.3  0022192AF09C Banana
192.168.1.99              FishyPC
```

Comment: I like this a lot as it is pretty adaptable as well. One thing I might change, unless there is an underlying reason that I'm missing, is that you don't need to create `$other` and since `ForEach` loops are faster than pipeline to `ForEach-Object`, you might want to change how `$leases` is handled to match your earlier loop. Something like this...`Foreach ($leaseRecord in $leases){[PSCustomObject]@{IP=$leaseRecord.IP; MAC=$hashRes[$leaseRecord.IP].MAC; Name=$leaseRecord.Name}}`

Comment: Create an inner join in the same loop with the outer join: `$reservations_outer=$reservations.clone(); $leases | foreach { $lease=$_; $reservations_outer | where { $_.IP -eq $lease.IP} | add-member -notepropertymembers @{name=$lease.name} -passthru } -outvariable reservations_inner`.